# Find All Instances in Excel Column

Tags: vba, excel

**CONTEXT**

I am trying to search in a specific column for all instances of "January" and then reference the row so I can copy the cell directly to the left of it.  The cells contain formulas so I am actually searching for the Value of the cell not the formula.

**PROBLEM**

I have been trying to test out and make sure it is referencing the right cell address (specifically, the row).  For each instance of January, it pastes "Testing" at the end of all values in the column instead of in FoundCell itself.  (ex. if January appeared 2 times, it would continuously loop "Testing" at the end of the column)

**Excel Sample**

```
Month      Month
January    =A2
February   =A3
April      =A4
April      =A5
January    =A6
December   =A7
```

**CURRENT CODE**

```
Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

Set myRange = Range("B:B")
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=January, after:=LastCell, LookIn:=xlValues)

'Test to see if anything was found
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
  FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
Do
    MsgBox "Found it!"
    FoundCell.Value = "Testing"
    Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(FoundCell)
  Loop While Not FoundCell Is Nothing And FoundCell.Address <> FirstFound
Else
 MsgBox "Not Found!"
End If

Set rng = FoundCell

Exit Sub
```

Please let me know if there is anything you see that could help!

Comment: January and Testing, they are not variables, you need to encase them on quotation marks. Find(what:="January"... FoundCell.Value = "Testing"

Comment: I recommend to use `Option Explicit` as very first statement of your module. This forces you to declare **all** variables properly and you would instantly see such issues. Especially for beginners this is very usefull.

Comment: @RicardoA you're right, but it is still not referencing the right cell address.

Comment: Why not? Hint: we can't answer that until/unless you provide additional information, such as example data that can be used to recreate the problem you're experiencing. Add more detail to provide a [mcve] :)

Comment: @DavidZemens I explained the issue/problem I was experiencing in the question and what happens whenever I run the code.  Please let me know what other information I can provide to help!

Comment: You explained the problem, but it is (currently) not possible for me (or anyone else) to reproduce the problem without making a bunch of guesses and other extraordinary effort to whip up some sample data. So, can you edit question to include example of a few rows of data for which this problem can be replicated?

Comment: @DavidZemens Sorry, you're correct!  I updated the problem and provided an excel sample that can be used to generate the same issues.

Comment: The code you've provided hits a Runtime 91 error (VBA doesn't short-circuit chained boolean expressions, so your `Loop While` statement is problematic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171559/discussion-between-yahtzee-and-david-zemens).

Comment: Is the source of the formula an actual date, or the word "January"? Also, does column B contain real dates or month names only?  Also - if you want to paste "Testing" not in `FoundCell` then you need to use `FoundCell.Offset(,1) = "Testing"`.  As you're then not changing the values being searched you can remove `Not FoundCell Is Nothing` as it will always find something as it loops around.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Column A contains the word "January" and column B contains the formulas as written.  This isn't the exact excel data, but is is the simplest way I could reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some modification, I am able to get your code to run. Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but based on the test data this code no longer hits the Runtime 91 error that your code encountered at the `Loop While`:

```
Sub foo()
Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

Set myRange = Range("B:B")
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:="January", after:=LastCell, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
    Do

        ' FoundCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        FoundCell.Offset(,1).Value = "Testing!"  '<~~ I'm writing out to the adjacent cell, just to be safe. Modify as needed.
        Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(FoundCell)

    Loop While (FoundCell.Address <> FirstFound)
End If

Set rng = FoundCell  '<~~ Careful, as this is only the LAST instance of FoundCell.

End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in terms of looping through the correct amount of instances and the right address.  My overall goal is to find each instance and copy the cell directly to the left of it.  That being said, how come MsgBox = "" & FoundCell.Offset(0,-1).Value placed in place of the "Testing" line shows error "function call on left hand side must return variant or object?"

Comment: Get rid of the `=` . `MsgBox` is a function call, you can't *assign to* it.

Answer (score -1):

You're getting the word "Testing" printing over and over because your loop is searching for the word "Testing", not "January".

```
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
  FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
Do
    MsgBox "Found it!"
    FoundCell.Value = "Testing"
    Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(FoundCell)
  Loop While Not FoundCell Is Nothing And FoundCell.Address <> FirstFound
Else
```

`FoundCell.Value = "Testing"` you're setting a cell value to Testing with this line

`Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(FoundCell)` now you're searching for the string "Testing".  FoundCell is a range.  I believe the default property for a cell range is the value of the cell (i.e. - "Testing")

So you're initially finding the string "January", changing it to "Testing" and then searching for the string "Testing" over and over, which you keep finding because you keeping writing it to a new cell with every loop iteration.

At least it seems like that's what's going on to me, I didn't actually try to run the code.  You could probably fix it by changing `Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(FoundCell)` to `Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(FoundCell.Value)`

Comment: Have to disagree there.  The OP is using the example found at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) which does update the found value and continues to find the next original value.

Comment: That's not how `FindNext` method works. That method takes a `Range` object as the `After` argument, so it looks for the next instance of whatever was specified by the original call to **`Find`**. It's not changing the `what` criteria of the original `Find`.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking it was the Find function, not FindNext.  Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: `FindNext(FoundCell.Value)` will actually raise a 1004 error.