# My code is to slow for what I request, how do I optimize it ? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have a program that read thousands of lines and return the value that I need. The problem is that request take a lot of time probably like 1min just to search and paste the value, even when I'm saving the code it takes a lot of time...

I think it is around this line that the code is slow :

```
If Sheets("MT950").Cells(line, 1) Like "-}{5:*" Then
```

Here is my code :

```
Function mysolde62(mycurrency As String, swift As String) As Double

Dim SearchString As String
Dim LastLine As Long, line As Long, k As Long
Dim mybegin As Long, myend As Long, test As Long, count As Long
Dim sign As String
Dim myvalue As Double

LastLine = Sheets("MT950").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

count = 0
myend = 1

For line = 1 To LastLine

If Sheets("MT950").Cells(line, 1) Like "-}{5:*" Then

    SearchString = Sheets("MT950").Range("A" & line).Value

    mypos = InStr(1, SearchString, swift, 1)
    If mypos <> 0 Then
        count = count + 1
    End If

End If
Next line

For k = 1 To count

For line = myend To LastLine
    If Sheets("MT950").Cells(line, 1) Like "-}{5:*" Then
        SearchString = Sheets("MT950").Range("A" & line).Value

        mypos = InStr(1, SearchString, swift, 1)
        If mypos <> 0 Then

            mybegin = line
            For linebis = mybegin To LastLine
                If Sheets("MT950").Cells(linebis, 1) Like ":62F:*" Then
                    SearchString = Sheets("MT950").Range("A" & linebis).Value

                    mypos = InStr(1, SearchString, mycurrency, 1)
                    If mypos <> 0 Then
                        myend = linebis
                        test = 1
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next linebis

            If test = 1 Then Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next line
If test = 1 Then Exit For
Next k


sign = Mid(Sheets("MT950").Cells(myend, 1).Value, 5, 1)
myvalue = Mid(Sheets("MT950").Cells(myend, 1).Value, 15)
If sign = "D" Then
mysolde62 = -myvalue
Else
mysolde62 = myvalue
End If


End Function
```

Comment: Load everything into variant arrays and loop those instead of constantly referring to the worksheet.

Comment: Hello, I think you should ask this question on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for your help !
Can you give me an example applicable to my code because I'm very new to VBA so I'm not sure to know how to do it.

Comment: As Scott Craner said, write everything to arrays. You can probably adapt the code in the following link to suit your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725360/vba-working-with-filtered-rows-and-specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-vs-copying-d/56726066#56726066

Comment: @bm13563 Thank you for the link !
I have tried to adapt it to my code it returns me the error #VALUE

Comment: Are you running this as a UDF?  If you're trying to debug it then you should call it from a Sub - you will then be able to see where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not an Excel dev and therefore not familiar with Excel's objects.

In general for VBA/VB6: avoid both the data type Variant and the Variant versions of functions, if possible. So use Mid$() instead of Mid(), Left$() instead of Left() etc. Like this line in your code:

```
sign = Mid(Sheets("MT950").Cells(myend, 1).Value, 5, 1)
```

This should read

```
sign = Mid$(Sheets("MT950").Cells(myend, 1).Value, 5, 1)
```

For general optimization tips for VB6/VBA, have a look here: https://www.aivosto.com/articles/stringopt.html

That said, I guess you're spot on with your observation of what's the culprit. The Like operator is slow compared to others. Now, looking at your code, it seems like you're searching for lines **starting** with "-}{5:" and later ":62F:". If that's the case, instead of

```
If Sheets("MT950").Cells(line, 1) Like "-}{5:*" Then
```

use something like

```
' Validate the first 5 characters
If Left$(Sheets("MT950").Cells(line, 1), 5) = "-}{5:" Then
```