# What is the most efficient way to copy rows from one workbook if the condition is met, to another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

If column G in workbook1 isn't empty, then copy that whole row to workbook2.

Now, the way I'd do it would simply be "Do Until" with an If statement inside.

I know that's probably far from the most efficient way of cracking this one, so I'm asking for help.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? A couple hundreds? Thousands? Hundreds of thousands?

Comment: Let's say it has to go through thousands of rows from Workbook1 and copy tens of them to Wb2.

Comment: Okay, to be clear: You have thousands of rows in workbook1, if and only if column G is not empty you want to copy the whole row to workbook 2?

Comment: The best way to do this with large amounts of data is with variant arrays. You should be able to adapt this answer to suit your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725360/vba-working-with-filtered-rows-and-specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-vs-copying-d/56726066#56726066

Comment: @JurasSulcas, do you mean Workbooks or worksheets? If Workbook, which is it just one sheet in both?

Comment: @Nacorid yes, correct.

Comment: @AAA. Workbooks. Yeah let's say they both have only one sheet, I'll adjust later based on the actual situation.

Comment: If you don't need to use code you could just filter non-blanks then copy and paste.

Comment: @JurasSulcas, check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than finding, copying and pasting for each cell, we first take the union of all the rows that match the given criterion, and then copy and paste just once. To use the solution below, make sure both workbooks are open and put their names in the strings below, as appropriate:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim wb1s as Worksheet, wb2s as Worksheet, rngG As Range, MySel As Range

'Change String as required based on your Workbook Name
'Change Worksheet number as required.
Set wb1s = Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
Set wb2s = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Worksheets(1)

With wb1s
    Set rngG = .Range("G1", .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In rngG
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        If MySel Is Nothing Then
            Set MySel = cell.EntireRow
        Else
            Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell.EntireRow)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If Not MySel Is Nothing Then MySel.Copy Destination:= wb2s.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Just from my first look, doesn't the last "If" copy every cell from wb1 to the same wb2 cell over and over, rewriting it every time?

Comment: Also, if you would be kind to give me a short comment about this part:
 If MySel Is Nothing Then
            Set MySel = cell.EntireRow
        Else
            Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell.EntireRow)

Comment: @JurasSulcas, the last `If` is executed just once, after gathering all the cells that need to be copied. Rather than copying and pasting each row separately, what we do is take the union of each row that meets the criterion in the `For` loop, and then paste once. The part you asked about does this: if MySel is empty, then MySel = cell. EntireRow. If MySel already had some rows, then Set MySel to be = Existing contents + new row. If this answer works for you, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Now it's all became super clear. Thank you, I will definitely use it for my future problems.

Comment: You are welcome. I will add some of that explanation to the answer.